# jquery load breaks html

Tags: jquery, regex, ajax, drupal-7

I'm loading div content with ajax call through jquery load function:

```
var $div = jQuery('<div>');        
$div.load(pageUrl+' .field-name-field-popup-info .field-item.even *');
```

It chooses the field containing html I'm using in a div in my current view. It works... but breaks html. Instead of

```
<p>Lorem ipsum<sup>1</sup></p>
```

I've got

```
<p>Lorem ipsum</p><sup>1</sup>
```

Can I make something to display my html correctly? Please help :)

---

EDIT

Same strange thing happens with ul tag, it closes the tag by force:

```
<ul></ul><li>Lorem</li>
```

Here's visual version of my markup:

[image: broken html]

---

EDIT 2

From what I've read inside load function source, the content is being parsed with jquery parseHtml function which finally relies on [such regex](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.12.4/src/core/var/rsingleTag.js):

```
// Match a standalone tag
return ( /^<([\w-]+)\s*\/?>(?:<\/\1>|)$/ );
```

I can't tell if this has an impact on my html. Maybe someone can tell ?

Comment: What's the HTML that's being loaded? For that to happen it means it's most likely badly formatted and the renderer is trying to fix it

Comment: the html is made inside drupal within ckeditor. It formats correctly, I've checked even with w3c validator.

Comment: I've asked the question on drupal answers, but they've asked me to move here :)

Comment: We can't really help you without knowing the HTML that's being loaded. If the format is being changed, it will be because of invalid HTML... somewhere.

Comment: I can't place here html, unfortunately. From what I can add, that, the xhr goes well, I can open the request in separate window, and it has the correct html. My issue happens when load script adds certain div into my jquery element. I've searched through jquery load api, but haven't found anything about sanitize or something close to.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't help you then. I'd suggest you check for mis-matched elements, and extra/missing closing tags.

Comment: maybe there's a chance, that someone encountered same issue,

Comment: I've updated the question, I've read through the jquery source and found parseHtml function, but can't figure is this an explanation why such things happen.